# Should Android system properties always be UTF-8

Tags: android

In [the JNI part of `android.os.SystemProperties`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_os_SystemProperties.cpp), both keys and values of system properties are assumed to be valid UTF-8. On the other hand, there's no such assumption in [bionic userland](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/bionic/system_properties.cpp).

If I create a malicious `/system/build.prop` with malicious non-UTF8 value, both `getprop` command and `property_get()` from bionic work while DalvikVM crashes with SIGABRT in `SystemProperties.get()`.

Are UTF-8 mandatary for system properties?

Are there official documentation or comments in codes mentioning it?